# Symfony 2.8 session storage in db + FOSUserbundle

Tags: php, symfony, session, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with session. I try to store session in database by using `PdoSessionHandler` and need to connect session with user. So I wrote a Login Listener:

```
class LoginListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
    * @var EntityManager
    */
    protected $entityManager;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * LoginListener constructor.
     *
     * @param Session       $session
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(Session $session, EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->session       = $session;
    }

    /**
     * @param InteractiveLoginEvent $event
     */
    public function onLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user      = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        if ($user) {
            $sessionId = $this->session->getId(); // hrj91gs3go3mlqat2hufrt54f6
            dump($sessionId);
            $sessions = $this
                ->entityManager
                ->getRepository('IntersynergyUserBundle:Sessions')
                ->findAll();
            dump($sessions); //hrj91gs3go3mlqat2hufrt54f6 this session id isn't in results

            $session = $this
                ->entityManager
                ->getRepository('IntersynergyUserBundle:Sessions')
                ->findOneBy(['id' => $sessionId]);
            dump($session); //empty results
            exit();
            if ($session) {
                $user->setSession($session);
                $this->entityManager->persist($user);
                $this->entityManager->flush();;
            }
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM      => 'onLogin',
            FOSUserEvents::SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN   => 'onLogin',
            FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_COMPLETED => 'onLogin',
            FOSUserEvents::SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN   => 'onLogin',
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN        => 'onLogin',
        ];
    }
 }
```

But when user starts logging on and when I try read session from database, I got empty doctrine results. It's very strange, because when I look into database session with this ID exists.

Comment: I think there is a general flaw in what you are trying to do. What if the user logs in through a second session (from another device for example)? Depending on how you have mapped `$user->session` (with orphanRemoval or without), either the second login will remove the old session (basically the user gets logged out on his first device), or the first session will stay around (still authenticated), but will no longer be connected to your user since the relation has been overwritten by the second login.

Comment: Hmm very interesting question. So what do you suggest to fix this issues? Move user_id to session table?

Comment: Thanks @aferber for your advice. I had some modification in my code. Tested and everything works correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think getRepository('IntersynergyUserBundle:Sessions')
            ->findOneBy(['id' => $sessionId]);
        dump($session); //empty results

Problem resides here. Can you post the dump($sessions) here? Are you sure it's mapped with the Id key?

Comment: No it isn't and class is mapped correct. Because this $sessions = $this->entityManager
            ->getRepository('IntersynergyUserBundle:Sessions')
            ->findAll();
give me a results but session with this id isn't in results. I founded this posts https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7885 but this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fix this just after get session id I save the session.

```
/**
 * @param User $user
 */
private function setUserSession(User $user)
{
    $sessionId = $this->session->getId();
    //this fix issues with regenerating session id
    $this->session->save();
    $session
        = $this
        ->entityManager
        ->getRepository('IntersynergyUserBundle:Sessions')
        ->findOneBy(['id' => $sessionId]);

    if ($session) {
        $session->setUser($user);
        $this->entityManager->persist($session);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

And modification in user and session entity:

User:

```
 userSessions:
        targetEntity: Intersynergy\UserBundle\Entity\Sessions
        mappedBy: user
```

Sessions:

```
/**
 * @var
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TwojTarotBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="userSessions")
 */
private $user;
```